# Changing data type in data frame

Tags: r, excel

I have some data tables in Excel spreadsheets which I am using in R. Some of the tables store numbers as text i.e. numeric values are stored as characters.

To clarify, it is not a formatting that is a problem but numbers themselves. The Excel (and R) sees such numbers as characters such as letters, rather then numbers.

Because formatting seems to be an issue, `addStyle` function in `openxlsx` did not work for me.

After some googling, I've decided to try and write a `for` loop that will check each value individually.I wrote a nested `for` loop that checks each value and overwrites it if it is a number (code is below).This seems to work logically but values do not get overwritten i.e. values that were stored as text are still there.

```
library(readxl) 
library(openxlsx)

wb<-loadWorkbook(choose.files())

data0<-as.data.frame(read_excel(choose.files(),sheet=1,range = "B1:E1131"))
data<-data0
for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(data)){
    if(is.numeric(as.numeric(data[j,i]))&&!is.na(as.numeric(data[j,i]))){
      data[j,i]<-as.numeric(data[j,i])
    }
  }
}
```

Desired outcome:

I would like to change data in column "Expenses" (in a picture below) to data in a column to its right via R.

[image]

Comment: I sometimes use the trick of multiplying by 1 ie = E1 * 1...

Comment: Why don't you just use `as.numeric` on the whole columns? e.g. `df$col1 <- as.numeric(df$col1)`?

Comment: You can use the `col_types`-argument in the `readxl::read_excel()`-function to force reading of text/numeric/date/... data

Comment: @Wimpel That seems to work quite nicely. Would it work, if say I have some empty cells or character cells in a column which I would like to be numeric? Also, are there situations when it will not work ( I had some situations when I used it before, in a big piece of code and it did not work).

Comment: @Num I have not yet encoutered problems with empty cells. My production data is well over 100k rows per excel-sheet.  For specific cases; you can define a vector with 'empty'-values by defining the `na`-argument form the `read_excel()`-function to handle cells with specific content as missing.

Comment: @Wimpel Alright. That sounds good! I am happy to accept it as an answer.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

coming from my comment:

You can use the `col_types`-argument in the `readxl::read_excel()`-function to force reading of text/numeric/date/... data